# ERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\a'. Azure Database for MySQL deployment

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-devops

I am getting an error when using ***Azure Database for MySQL deployment*** task in azure devops. I am getting the below error in logs only when using ScriptFile option in the devops task where I select the file from the artifact.

Here is the complete path I am using: **$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_artifact/drop/migrations/AppDbContext.sql**

But it works fine when inline script option is selected. I downloaded the AppDbContext.sql file from the artifact and used it as inline script. It ran through successfully. I am not sure why it is not working when ScriptFile option is selected in the task.

Please see the below logs:

Task : Azure Database for MySQL deployment

Description : Run your scripts and make changes to your Azure Database for MySQL 2021-02-08T19:14:18.3011839Z Version : 1.182.1

Author : Microsoft Corporation 2021-02-08T19:14:18.3012657Z Help : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-mysql-deployment

[command]C:\mysql-5.7.21-winx64\bin\mysql.exe -hdatabase.database.azure.com -usomeusername -p***

mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.

[command]C:\mysql-5.7.21-winx64\bin\mysql.exe -hdatabase.database.azure.com -usomeusername -p*** "-eCREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `database` ;"

mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.

[command]C:\mysql-5.7.21-winx64\bin\mysql.exe -hdatabase.database.azure.com -usomeusername -p*** -Ddatabase -e "source D:\a\r1\a_artifact\drop\migrations\AppDbContext.sql;"

mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.

**ERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\a'.**

**##[error]Error: The process 'C:\mysql-5.7.21-winx64\bin\mysql.exe' failed with exit code 1**

##[section]

Finishing: Execute Azure MySQL : SqlTaskFile

Comment: Looks like a path escaping issue to me. Did you try wrapping the path in single quotes?

Comment: Tried that now, it is trying to find the path with the quotes now.

Comment: @RL89, So does Daniel Mann's suggestion work for you? if not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue? If, yes, you could share the solution as answer for others who has the same issue.

Comment: @Joy No it didnt work. It started finding the path with the quotes. I have raised it with microsoft, as soon as I have something I'll update it here.